# Send html page to client

Tags: node.js, express

I form the markup of the html page and write to the variable `htmlToSend`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Hyperspotters</title>
</head>
    <body style="margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            <header>
                <div style="background: #3366CD; padding: 10px">
                ....
```

I need to return it to the client.

I promoted so

```
            let htmlToSend = func.statusСheck(success, replacements);
            return res.sendFile(htmlToSend);
```

and

```
            let htmlToSend = func.statusСheck(success, replacements);
            return res.render(htmlToSend);
```

How do I get my markup back to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the middleware functions of `Express.js` expose the `req` and the `res` objects, with the `res` beeing the response object, which you use to send responses back to a client.

Example:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

});
```

As stated by @jacob already, use the `send` function of the response object to send a reply to the client. You should, however, send the data as string (not buffer), because using a buffer leads to the data beeing interpreted as binary data, but clearly you are sending text. Also, using a buffer makes express set a Content-Type of 'application/octet-stream', which is also not what you want. Instead, set it to 'text/html'.

```
app.use("/", function (req, res, next) {
   res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   res.send(htmlToSend);
});
```

See: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html
And also: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

If you want to render HTML, try this code.

```
res.render('index', function(err, html) {
  res.send(html);
});
```

where `index` is the view

If you want to respond with HTML content, try this code.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(new Buffer(htmlToSend));
```

don't forget to set `Content-Type`.

Comment: I tried both methods and gives an error `path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Comment: you may try `res.sendFile(__dirname + htmlToSend);`. remember `htmlToSend` must be a file in this case, not HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this one of the following ways:

```
// serve your files as static
// 'public' -- your static files folder, set path accordingly
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + 'public'))
```

Assuming you've `index.html` in your `public` folder, you can access file like `yourhost:port/static/index.html`

Or use template engine through `view engine` (like `ejs`, 'pug', `nunjucks` etc) like:

```
// assuming you use ejs
const ejs = require('ejs'); // install ejs package
// your views folder (say folder named "views")
app.set('views', __dirname + 'views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// Assuming you've index.ejs in your views folder
// in your router
...
res.render('index');
```

More about [`templating`](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html) [`engines`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) and serving static [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)